# Android Sqlite3 database: Cursor in SQLite is not returning null?

Tags: android, sqlite

Could someone advise me why I am only getting `true` result, even though that record does not exist in my database?

For clarification, in my table, `_id` is the telephone number.

Here's my code:

```
public boolean checkifExists(String number){
    String[] columns = new String[]{"_id"};
    String[] wehreargs = new String[]{number};
    this.openDataBase();
    if (myDataBase.query("mytable", columns, "_id=?", wehreargs, null, null, null)==null){
        myDataBase.query("mytable", columns, "_id=?", wehreargs, null, null, null).close();
        this.close();
    return false;
    } else {
        myDataBase.query("mytable", columns, "_id=?", wehreargs, null, null, null).close();
        this.close();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DougCurrie mentions: Query is returning non-Null cursors only: revised your code:

```
public boolean checkifExists(String number){
    String[] columns = new String[]{"_id"};
    String[] wehreargs = new String[]{number};
    this.openDataBase();
    Cursor c = myDataBase.query("mytable", columns, "_id=?", wehreargs, null, null, null)
    boolean hasEntry = c.moveToFirst()
    c.close();
    this.close()
    return hasEntry;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`query` returns a [`Cursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) which is always non-null. You must read from the [`Cursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) to get the result of the `query`